# Numba jit nopython - how to test for null pointer

Tags: numba

After using numba a lot, I'm stuck with a very basic problem. How to check for NULL pointer ?
It must be trivial but I cannot seem to figure it out. Please see comments in the snippet below.
I'm trying to implement a C callback

```py
import numba as nb
from numba.core.typing import cffi_utils,ctypes_utils
import ctypes
from cffi import FFI
ffi=FFI()
ffi.cdef('void (*fun)(int n, double* x)')
sig = cffi_utils.map_type(ffi.typeof('fun'))

# how to define NullPtr ?
# None of the following works
NullPtr = ffi.NULL 
NullPtr = None
NullPtr = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)()

@nb.cfunc(sig)
def fun(n, x):
    # if x: doesn't  work
    # if x == 0: doesn't  work
    if x == NullPtr: # doesn't  work either 
        pass
    else:
        # do stuff with x
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came up with a solution but I can hardly believe it should be like this

```py
from numba.extending import intrinsic
from numba.core import cgutils

@intrinsic
def is_null_ptr(typingctx, src):
    if isinstance(src, types.CPointer):
        sig  = types.boolean(src)
        def codegen(context, builder, signature, args):
            [src] = args
            return cgutils.is_null(builder,src)
        return sig, codegen
```

usage:

```py
@nb.cfunc(sig)
def fun(n, x):
    if is_null_ptr(x):
        pass
    else:
        # do stuff with x
        pass
```